# Select Drop Down Menu is not fully visible

Tags: reactjs, select, html-table, drop-down-menu, option-type

[image: I use the Select tag in td but options are not fully visible to me as you can see in this picture. i have used overflow : visible; and z-index : 999; but problems remains there.]

[Code which I write for select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU9RC.png)

Comment: What does your code looks like on your attempts? What exactly have you tried since yesterday? Please provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: <td >
                                                <select class="td-input">
                                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>